# Repeating macro n times

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to ask if there's some way, to "repeat" macro n times automatically - by automatically I mean compile time, I want to do something like this:

```
#define foo _asm mov eax, eax
#define bar(x) //I don't know how can I do it
int main()
{
    bar(5); //would generate 5 times _asm mov eax, eax
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can embed macros in other macros but I don't know how can I do it something exactly n times. I want to use it in random-sized junk generator

Comment: You can't do this with macros but you can do this with template

Comment: if you want to discuss in respect of `c++`, don't tag `c`.

Comment: Yeah and the Boost preprocessing sub-library provides that. As I recall it involves a lot of boiler-plate code to create such solution yourself. Also, C++ compilers notoriously differ in their exact preprocessor syntax and semantics, few if any are 100% standard-conforming.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf this is not a problem - I want solution only for windows - vs

Comment: @wowofbob can you post any snippet?

Comment: @wowofbob I would be interested how you solve this with a template regarding this inline assembler code.

Comment: @encoreleet: Most times a simple loop is better. And where that isn't good enough, some template thing is indicated. Only after considering those, turn to Boost macro iteration (e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Comment: It's more like recursion: http://goo.gl/ye5lVF

Comment: @wowofbob oh, I didnt think that this would be that easy, I've never looked at disassembly of recursive templates, my bad

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [This](http://goo.gl/K52VZU) solution works in my VS2013, but I don't know how to test registers there.

Comment: @wowofbob And the function call frames put around the `asm` statements? Did you check the produced assembly output?

Comment: @wowofbob post an answer and I will accept it, this is exactly what I was looking for :D
code: http://pastebin.com/vEGZR8YW
produces assembly: http://pastebin.com/29Pn4H88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using recoursive template:

```
// recoursive step
template
  <
    size_t   count
  >
void n_asm() {
  _asm mov eax, eax
  n_asm<count - 1>();
}

// base of recursion
template<>
void n_asm<0>() {

}

int main()
{
   n_asm<5>(); 

   return 0;
}
```